# Issues in linking to another page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am unable to link certain text (text that I want to link is in h6) to another page I've created. I'm following the standard   format but somehow it is not working. Please help me!

HTML Code:

```
    <ul class="ei-slider-large">
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/large/1.jpg" alt="slider1"/>
                        <div class="ei-title">
                            <h2>Welcome</h2> <br>
                            <h3>Child at Street 11</h3>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/large/2.jpg" alt="slider2" />
                        <div class="ei-title2">
                            <h4>Enrol</h4><br>
                            <h5>Every child deserves to have an early education</h5><br>
                         <h6><a href="enrol.html">Enrol Now</a></h6> 
                        <br>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/large/3.jpg" alt="slider3" />
                        <div class="ei-title2">
                            <h4>Donate</h4><br>
                            <h5>Give back to our society by helping the underpriviledged</h5><br>
                             <h6><a href="donate.html">Donate Now</a></h6>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/large/4.jpg" alt="slider4"/>
                        <div class="ei-title2">
                            <h4>Volunteer</h4><br>
                            <h5>Lend us your hand with our many volunteer opportunities</h5><br>
                             <h6><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer Now</a></h6>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

CSS Style:

```
    .ei-title2 h6{
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration:underline;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #000;
letter-spacing:.02em;
background:#ffd40b;
display:inline;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;}

    .ei-title2 h6 a:hover{
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px;}
```

Thanks kind soul!

Comment: Are all the hyperlinks in the `<h6>` tags not working, or just one? Is it going to an outside url, or doing nothing at all? If it is going to a url, what is it going to?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?  The links seem to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pe29jLr6/

Comment: nothing wrong with the links here with me

Comment: All of them. It doesnt turn out to as a link at all! :( each of the h6 links will be going to another page created. e.g. enrol.html, volunteer.html

Comment: @user3198735 So they're going to another pages ?
What're you trying to do !